How to set the height of the table based on the displayed data in ag-grid-vue3
And I have one more question regarding the ag-grid.
Could you please let me know how I can customize the height of the table?
It seems the table has only initial height and immutable rely on the status.
<ag-grid-vue
        :defaultColDef='defaultColDef'
        style='width: 100%; height: 350px;'
        class='ag-theme-quartz
        :columnDefs='columnDefs'
        :rowData='rowData'
        rowSelection='multiple'
      >

But I need to customize the table so that the height depends on the displayed data.

What do you see in your browser devtools regarding the CSS of the element you're trying to customize?
